# pip install dandi, but dandi command not found

Tags: pip

I did `pip install dandi`.
When I do this:

```
dandi download https://dandiarchive.org/dandiset/000253/draft
```

It says `dandi not recognized as internal or external command`. What is the issue?

I tried running as administrator and cloned the dandi repository from github, but don't know what commands to run to get it to work.